# sqlstate[hy000] [2002] connection refused in laravel 5.2.29 trying migrations

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm trying to execute migrations in my laravel_cms example database

I put the correct parameters in the `.env` file in my project

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=8889
DB_DATABASE=laravel_cms
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

The default password in MAMP PRO to root user is root but I have changed it. But that is not a problem because I access using terminal with tag password

The port than MAMP PRO uses is 8889

But when I execute this command in the larval project: 
    php artisan migrate

I get this error

> [PDOException]
>   SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Any idea please?

Regards

Comment: Check `config/database.php` file configurations, whether it's reading from`.env` or the values set there.

Comment: dañase.php is reading from .env the values

Comment: Have you tried changing 127.0.0.1 to localhost? MAMP is kinda weird like that.

Comment: Yes I have tried with localhost too but does not work

Comment: is your server actually running?